# Magento 2 Controller Post throwing 404 error

Tags: php, magento2

I've hit an issue trying to add a new action to an existing route in Magento 2.

I've created a new module, registered it and created a new action extending the existing add to cart functionality. I had this working on an existing project, but had to port it over to a new installation. Now when I attempt to `POST` to the path: `<magentourl>/checkout/cart/addbulk`, it throws a `404`. A `GET` request will hit the execute method and creates the log entry.

The following are the components of the module.

`app/code/Test/Checkout/etc/module.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Checkout" schema_version="2.0.0" setup_version="2.0.3">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`app/code/Test/Checkout/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkout" frontName="checkout">
            <module name="Test_Checkout" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`app/code/Test/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Addbulk.php`

```php
<?php
namespace Test\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Addbulk extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{
    
    public function execute()
    {
        $items = $this->getRequest()->getParam('item', []);
        $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')>addDebug('Posting data to addBulk');
        
        ...

        return $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

I've enabled the module, run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, cleared cache and then attempted to post.
When I do a `POST`, it returns a `404` error, on a `GET` it creates the log entry as expected.

Does anyone have any idea why this module would not have migrated correctly, or anything else I would need to add to get this working?

Comment: What deploy mode have you set? Have you tried to clear all cache files + generated code files also on your filesystem?

Comment: You are missing a `-` in `>addDebug('Posting data to addBulk');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the environment itself was broken. I installed my module on a fresh install of magento 2 successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this after creating your controller?

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Or enabling `Developer mode`?

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/magento cache:disable
```

Clear the contents of folders

> **generated/code**
>   and 
>   **generated/metadata**.

Check PHP-FPM or OPCACHE cache also.